# How to Geocode an address where the reference data has an address range in a single field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, geocoding

I would like use something like the "US Address - One Range"([Commonly used locator styles](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/geocoding/commonly-used-locator-styles.htm)) where there is a **from address** and **to address**. However it requires side of street information and my range of addresses are in a single field.

My reference data looks like this:

```
+----------------+---------+
|     Field      |  Value  |
+----------------+---------+
| Shape          | Polygon |
| Street_Number  | 45-55   |
| Street_Name    | Foo     |
+----------------+---------+
```

So overall I would like to Geocode multiple addresses to a single point by creating a Address Locator that takes a range of house numbers.

I have looked at this [Customizing ArcGIS 10 locators (An Esri Geocoding Technical Paper)](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=aeb00de638f3492a93308a4a03183c7d)

It looks promising but much more complicated than what I am looking for. Is this the only way to Geocode my reference data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up generating the missing points in the range. (45-55 becomes 45,46,47,..,55) with all the points in the range stacked on top of each other using this script.

```
import arcpy
import os

def main():
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    InFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    OutFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

    Folder = os.path.dirname(OutFC)
    Name   = os.path.basename(OutFC)

    desc = arcpy.Describe(InFC)
    SR   = desc.spatialReference

    if arcpy.Exists(OutFC):
        arcpy.DeleteRows_management(OutFC)
    else:
        arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(Folder, Name,"POINT", template = 
InFC, spatial_reference = SR)

    fillHouseNumberRange(InFC, OutFC)


def fillHouseNumberRange(InFeat, OutFeat):
    in_fields = ["SHAPE@", "Street_Number", "Street_Name"]
    out_fields = ["SHAPE@XY", "Street_Number", "Street_Name"]
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(OutFeat, out_fields) as iCur, \
            arcpy.da.SearchCursor(InFeat,in_fields) as sCur:
        for sRow in sCur:
            cent = sRow[0].centroid
            st_nbr = sRow[1]
            fename = sRow[2]
            if len(st_nbr.split("-")) == 2:
                try:
                    st_range = st_nbr.split("-")
                    start = int(st_range[0])
                    end = int(st_range[1])
                    for i in range(start, end+1):
                        iCur.insertRow([(cent.X,cent.Y), str(i), fename])
                except:
                    iCur.insertRow([(cent.X,cent.Y), st_nbr, fename])
            else:
                iCur.insertRow([(cent.X,cent.Y), st_nbr, fename])




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then made an address locator with the "US Address - Single House" style with the new out features.